Installing ubuntu failed after selecting "try and install ubuntu"
I am trying to install Ubuntu on my newly built PC, but so far I always stuck at the booting phase.
Here is what I have done.

Install Windows
free some space (500GiB) for Ubuntu
download Ubuntu desktop here https://ubuntu.com/desktop
use Rufus to create a bootable USB drive
disable Secure Boot and Fast Boot
restart my PC and use f12 to choose boot from the USB drive
I saw  this screen selection screen
then select try and install ubuntu, then it got stuck at this screen stuck screen

A few things I tried:

connecting monitor to motherboard video output same thing
tried the graphics safe mode, same thing

My build:
   Gigabyte x870 motherboard
   9800x3d
   Gigabyte 4060 GPU

Try booting with Ubuntu Safe Graphics

yeah I have tried booting with the safe graphics mode and did not work

I would expect you need safe graphics with your GPU. But system is so new you may need 24.10 or even the testing 25.04 which will not be released until April 2015. You then are testing the new version, need to report bugs/issues. and expect some breakage. It will get many updates, so history will be larger than normal, so new install not required when released, but good to reinstall, just to houseclean. Very new hardware requires newest kernel & drivers which are eventually added to LTS versions, but short term releases get them sooner. If LTS version works always best to use that.

Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware to latest available. Even new hardware may have newer firmware available. If live installer works in live mode you can run this to know versions. Compare to vendors support site
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &
udisksctl status
